# Package name alias or nickname

Tags: java, android, xml, package, extend

Is it possible to create a nickname for a package name, that I can refer in xml file?

I don't want to write the whole package name e.g. com.example.go.deck.today instead can I create an alias and refer that alias?

I'd like to refer an alias or nick instead of the package name in an android/layout XML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android by itself does not provide such facility. However you can use the ant to do it for you. You could write a custom build.xml, customizing the target `<target name="-code-gen">` to do token replacement before the `R` class is generated.  You could add the rule :

```
<replace file="targetFile" token="@PACKAGE_ALIAS@" value="com.example.go.deck.today"/>
```

this would replace every occurrence of `@PACKAGE_ALIAS@` by `com.example.go.deck.today` in the `targetFile`.

I am not an `ant` specialist but based on past experience I would say that it would not be hard to write a rule that could scan all file in the `res` dir.

Answer (score 9):

No, sorry, this is not possible, at least not directly within the Android toolset.

Answer (score 2):

Though its not directly possible to refer to a package name, however,
 for using a `‘resource’` in a `xml` or code is :

```
package.R.resource_type.resource_name
```

and

```
@[package:]resource_type/resource_name
```

NOTE: package here does not mean `‘java package’` but `package == application`, so if you are accessing a resource which is defined in your own app you can skip it. Thats why we use `@strings/name` or directly `R.strings.name`. Similarly to use resources defined by android we will use `@android:string/name` or `android.R.string.name`