# Android: Is it possible to alias R from app and lib to distinguish between the two?

Tags: android, android-library

Can I somehow alias a generated `R` file from a library and a generated `R` file from an application?

`IE`: I have two projects, one being a library. I reference the library in the application.
The library creates one `R` file, the application creates two: `com.example.mapplication.R` and the `R` from the referenced library, `com.example.mlibrary.R`. However, since I want to use both frequently in the application, I want to alias both the `R` classes. For example, call the library `R` something like `libR` and the app `R` something like `appR`.

I tried a couple of things which are of such stupidity, I won't even fully mention them, but I did some things like `private com.example.mapplication.R appR = com.example.mapplication.R` (immediately realising this wasn't gonna work), and `private Class<com.example.mapplication.R> appRclass = com.example.mapplication.R.class;`, but that didn't give me the desired effect. I do, however, use the latter method and some reflection to make it possible to be able to get the field and inner classes like this:

```
Class<com.example.mapplication.R> appRclass = com.example.mapplication.R.class;
int activity_main_layoutid = Toolkit.getFromClass(appR).
         getMeTheInnerClass("layout").getMeAField("activity_main");
```

I haven't fully implemented the Toolkit method, but as we all know refletion can do this kind of stuff, but at the end of the day it's just as much work as just typing `com.example.mapplication.R` or `com.example.mlibrary.R` everywhere.

So to wrap thing up: **Is it possible to alias multiple `R`'s** so that I can use `appR` and `libR` to distinguish the two?

Comment: Doesn't the `appR` already have everything in the `libR`?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214317/package-name-alias-or-nickname

Comment: i m not sure but can u extend the two classes without inducing compilation error? -ie create libR extends bla.lib.R and appR extends bla.app.R

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Nice catch, but `R` is `final`.

Comment: @K-ballo I did not actually know that until now, I did know the application would get the `R` from the library, but not that all fields would get copied into the application `R`. Probably because `Eclipse` always auto-imports the `R` from the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish we could, but according to what I know, it isn't possible, at least not yet.

I also wish we could put resources in sub folders, but even this is impossible.

What you can do is setting a unique prefix (rename each resource file) for each library, as it's done by some third party libraries (like *actionBarSherlock*, which uses "abs" as the prefix).

Alternatively, you can have a special trick and put the files in the **src** folder and reach them from there, but that's more of a workaround, since the `R` won't have a reference to any of the resources there.

For example, you can put an image called **image.png** into the **src/com/company/app_name**, and then create a bitmap from it using:

```
final InputStream fis = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/company/app_name/image.png");
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

By the way, if you've thought of using the assets folder, you can't do it for library projects, since it requires you to have the files in the project that uses the library project. It will work, but it misses the encapsulation idea...

Comment: Thanks, after messing around for a few days, I was getting the feeling this wasn't gonna be easy if possible at all, so it's nice to have some closure.